# Can OpenJPA be used to reverse map a database view?

Tags: openjpa

I have database views that have a column that uniquely identifies each row in the view.  This column could be used as the primary key even though the view doesn't have a primary key in its definition (DDL) because it's a view.

OpenJPA is refusing to map the views to Java POJOs because there is no primary key.

I have a list of views and primary keys and I have a ReverseCustomizer.  Is it possible I can give OpenJPA the column/field to be used as the primary key / id for each view / class?

Currently, the reverse mapping tool calls `unmappedTable` for each view and I'd like to tell the reverse mapper to do the mapping with the primary key I provide.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to help you get started.

```
public class MyDBReverseCustomizer implements ReverseCustomizer {

    private ReverseMappingTool rmt;

    @Override
    public void setTool(ReverseMappingTool rmt) {
        this.rmt = rmt;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean unmappedTable(Table table) {
        // this method is called to give this class an opportunity to map the
        // table which would not be mapped otherwise.  Returning false says
        // the table wasn't mapped here.
        //Class klass = rmt.generateClass(table.getIdentifier().getName(), null);
        String packageName = rmt.getPackageName();
        String tableName = table.getIdentifier().getName();
        String className = NameConverters.convertTableName(tableName);
        Class klass = rmt.generateClass(packageName+"."+className, null);
        ClassMapping cls = rmt.newClassMapping(klass, table);
        Column pk = null;
        for ( Column column : table.getColumns() ) {
            String columnName = column.getIdentifier().getName();
            String fieldName = rmt.getFieldName(columnName, cls);
            Class type = rmt.getFieldType(column, false);
            FieldMapping field = cls.addDeclaredFieldMapping(fieldName, type);
            field.setExplicit(true);
            field.setColumns(new Column[]{column});
            // TODO: set the appropriate strategy for non-primitive types.
            field.setStrategy(new PrimitiveFieldStrategy(), null);
            if ("MODEL_VIEW".equals(tableName) && "MODEL_ID".equals(columnName)) {
                pk = column;
                field.setPrimaryKey(true);
            }
            customize(field);
        }
        //cls.setPrimaryKeyColumns(new Column[]{pk});
        cls.setObjectIdType(null, false);
        cls.setIdentityType(ClassMapping.ID_DATASTORE);
        cls.setStrategy(new FullClassStrategy(), null);
        return true;
    }

    ...

}
```